# How should I prove this functional? What technique should I apply?

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

Consider the functional $S[y]=\int_{1}^{2}ln(1+x^2y')dx, y(1)=0, y(2)=A$, where $A$ is a constant and $y$ is a continuously differentiable function for $1\leq x\leq 2$. Let $h$ be a continuously differentiable function for $1\leq x\leq 2$, and let $\epsilon$ be a constant. Let $\bigtriangleup=S[y+\epsilon h]-S[y]$. Show that $\bigtriangleup=\epsilon\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^2h'}{1+x^2y'}dx-\frac{\epsilon^2}{2}\int_{1}^{2}\frac{x^4h'^2}{(1+x^2y')^2}dx+O(\epsilon^3)$.

Here's my work:
Let $\bigtriangleup=S[y+\epsilon h]-S[y]$.

Then $\bigtriangleup=\int_{1}^{2}ln(1+x^2(y'+\epsilon h'))dx-\int_{1}^{2}ln(1+x^2y')dx=\int_{1}^{2}ln(\frac{1+x^2(y'+\epsilon h')}{1+x^2y'})dx$.

From here what should I do in order to complete the proof?

Comment: Divide through by $\epsilon$ and take the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$. You should end up having to differentiate the logarithm and end up with something linear in $h$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\varepsilon$ has to be interpreted as an infinitesimal quantity, you should use the second-order Taylor expansion of the logarithm, i.e.
$$
\ln(1+z) = \displaystyle\sum_{k\ge1} (-1)^{k+1}\frac{z^k}{k} = z - \frac{z^2}{2} + \mathcal{O}(z^3),
$$
as follows :
$$
\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2(y'+\varepsilon h')}{1+x^2y'}\right) 
   = \ln\left(1+\frac{\varepsilon x^2h'}{1+x^2y'}\right) 
   = \frac{\varepsilon x^2h'}{1+x^2y'} - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\varepsilon x^2h'}{1+x^2y'}\right)^2 + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^3)
$$
And the job is done !

Comment: This is a lot easier than I thought before! Thank you so much for the help!